# Background image not showing IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, background-image

For some reason, the background image is not showing up in IE8 and IE9. It shows up in IE10, Chrome, and Firefox.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.addCartButton 
{
    background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09);
    background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09);
    background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09);
    background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, linear-gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09);
}
```

Comment: multiple bg's aren't supported by IE < 10

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: You mean I can't have both a background image and gradient?

Comment: Nope. As far I know, a gradient count as a background image. If browser does not support css 3 multiple backgrounds, it will fail for all (count as invalid property value). I know IE9 somewhat supports multiple bgs but it's alot buggy (check this http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds at known issues). And since IE9 does not know about css 3 gradient, it makes entire declaration invalid ( http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[CSS3 multiple background](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) isn't supported by IE 8 and below. So the comma separated background value it's invalid thus will not work.

And it does not work on IE9, even when it support multiple backgrounds (buggy but it does) because IE9 does NOT support [CSS3 Gradient](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) so again it makes entire declaration invalid.

I suggest you use `!important` on the multiple background declarations but make a single background declaration as last in the line, so IE9 and below can display at least one of the BG's:

```
background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09) !important;
background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09) !important;
background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09) !important;
background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat, linear- gradient(top,#74c163,#1d7a09) !important;
background: url('/images/cartWhite.png') 18px 11px no-repeat; /* for IE9 and below */
```

---

As another option, you could use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background). Example:

```
#myElement {
    behavior: url(http://path/to/pie/PIE.htc);
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat #CCC; /*non-CSS3 browsers will use this*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#CCC) to(#EEE)); /*old webkit*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*new webkit*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*gecko*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*IE10 preview*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*opera 11.10+*/
    background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*future CSS3 browsers*/
    -pie-background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#CCC, #EEE); /*PIE*/
}
```

Keep in mind it will only work if url of `behavior` is on the same domain. [Read more](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths).