# Background image css not display in IE7, IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to give a background image to div using css. This is my css

```
.header {
    background: url("../images/header1.png") no-repeat scroll right 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 55px;
    padding: 5px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works fine on firefox & chrome even on IE9 & IE10 also but its not working in IE8 or older versions. I have googled & also refered this question but its not helping.

[Background image not showing IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086034/background-image-not-showing-ie8)

Comment: `rgba` is not supported on IE<9. Anyway a fiddle may help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295928/background-image-css-fails-to-display-in-ie7-8

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: thanks.. It worked after removing rgba()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

rgba not supported in IE7/ IE8
http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

```
 .header
    {
    background: url("../images/header1.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right 15px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 5px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
```